# Regarding ArrayList in Android

Tags: android, arraylist

In android, I am using an Arraylist. In Arraylist I used to add all items. But when I try to retieve all items from that Arraylist, I am able to get only the last element that I added in all positions.
Can you please tell me how can I get all the elements??

Here is an example of code type:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>;
arrayList.add(item1);
arrayList.add(item2);
arrayList.add(item3);
arrayList.add(item4);
```

and when I try to retrieve this I get only the item4 in all positions.

```
for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
    Log.d("item",arrayList.get(i).toString);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `item1`, ..., `item3` are distinct from `item4`? Also, your loop termination condition should be `i<arrayList.size()` (actually calling `size()`), not `i<arrayList.size`. And you should be calling `toString()` in the loop body.

Comment: yes item1,item2,item3 are different from item4 because as i remove the item4 and again run the code then it gives me the value of item3 at all positions.

Comment: hey sorry,i have written size() in my code

Comment: Are item 1-4 created in a loop? Please show that loop if so.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in your code. This will work perfectly. Can you show us your original code.

Comment: no items are created in a different manner and just adding them one by one in a list.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<roughList.size();i++)
              {
               Log.e("TilluGang",roughList.get(i).toString());
              }

Comment: rough.setRowsValue(branchHeaderTextView.getText().toString());
              roughList.add(rough);
      rough.setRowsValue(cashHeaderTextView.getText().toString());
roughList.add(rough);

Comment: here i am savinng the rough object in roughlist

Comment: You should use `Log.d(TAG, message)` instead of `System.out.println(message);`.

Comment: rough.setRowsValue(branchHeaderTextView.getText().toString()); roughList.add(rough);                                           rough = new Object(); rough.setRowsValue(cashHeaderTextView.getText().toString());        roughList.add(rough);                                                Every time create new object,set data to this and add this to list

Comment: Update your question with the code please.

Comment: hey but my object is final

Comment: final  objects initialize only once.Please try like this and update what the result is.

Comment: @DevuSoman hey thanks for the suggestion!!!!!it works for me...heyy jst tell me is it necessary to create everytime new object??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rough.setRowsValue(branchHeaderTextView.getText().toString()); 
roughList.add(rough); rough = new Object();  
rough.setRowsValue(cashHeaderTextView.getText().toString()); 
roughList.add(rough);
```

Create new object,set data to this and add this to list

Comment: I am not sure.I think it is due to garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to brackets at the end of `ArrayList`

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code works fine for me.Try it..

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
stringList.add("Item1");
stringList.add("Item2");
stringList.add("Item3");
stringList.add("Item4");

for(String item: stringList){
    System.out.println("retrieved element: " + item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity lies in the items. The only reason I see this might happen is that the items are all references to the same memory location.